# Gitlab runner immediately fails & doesn't create the build folder. Works well when its run on debug mode

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm quite new to gitlab CI and have setup my server at DigitalOcean with gitlab-runnner. When I start the gitlab-runner by the command `sudo gitlab-runner start`, it runs fine and I confirm it with `gitlab-runner status`. But, the job fails immediately as per this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1VL9.png)

However, when I run `gitlab-runner --debug run`, the job runs perfectly fine. 
I want to run **gitlab-runner as a background service** but its not running my jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue from gitlab. For me, the solution was to comment out the clear console command from .bash_logout file in the gitlab-runner home folder. 
More information about this issue can be taken from a bug logged at gitlab.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4449